# diffpatterns returns patterns with no match value in any columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

There are some cases where diffpatterns returns matches with no value for any of the columns in the input dataset.

What do these rows represent?

For example, (ClientRequestId 'KE.RunQuery;96f82b6d-f382-4ca2-aa5e-7ffc27a8a8a0'),
I sometimes get multiple rows which don't have any value in any column.

What do these rows represent? Why are there multiple of them in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the source expression contains string columns with many empty string values. The default wildcard ("any value") for string columns is an empty string which means you can't distinguish between an explicit empty string value and a wildcard string.

You could change the default wildcard for strings, for example to '*' value to distinguish the wildcard from an explicit empty string:

```
T 
| evaluate diffpatterns(SplitColumn, SplitValueA, SplitValueB, "~", "~", "~", "*")
```

More details can found in the [diffpatterns() docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/diffpatternsplugin)